# Processing Numerical Data in a Multivalue Column

Tags: r

I am trying to process data read from a csv file in which columns contain strings consisting of a list of numerical data entries. For example:

```
"ID","Nums"
"bob","1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"
"ana","8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1"
```

If I were, for example, to try to compute the mean for a given row of nums, how might I approach doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `strsplit` to split on `,` and then applying `mapply` function as:

```
df$mean <- mapply(function(x)mean(as.numeric(x)), strsplit(df$Nums, ","))
df
#   ID                   Nums mean
#1 bob 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8   4.5
#2 ana 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1   4.5
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.csv(text =
'"ID","Nums"
"bob","1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"
"ana","8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1"', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: The above code generates "error in strsplit(df$Nums, ",") : non-character argument"

Comment: @martinsarif please check type of `Nums` column. It should be character. You can first try with data given by me along with my answer.

Comment: How might this solution change if I were trying to apply an operation to all of the elements of nums? For example, computing the mean of the nums for every ID.

Comment: @martinsarif Solution depends on situations. Please note currently calculation of `mean` for each ID. Now if want to apply an operation on each item of `Nums` and if number of items are fixed (say 8) you can probably use `tidyr::separate` to create separate column for each one of them and then you can perform any operation. Otherwise if number is not fixed then you have option to use `lapply` and transform data into a list.